# select * from table1, table2 where table1.id = 1 showing values with other id

Tags: mysql

I just can't see the problem with how I'm making my foreign keys and I'm just really confused why I keep getting the wrong result. Here are screenshots from my workbench

[image]

Here are my tables:

[image]
[image]

And here's my diagram

[image]

I've also tried to normalize my tables and I was kinda expecting my query to return a similar result like in the sample table (Questions table) where it will only show 2 results since I want to query `where idsurvey = 1` I made in this image:
[image]

My question is that, how do I fix my foreign key so that if I want to query

```
select * from survey.survey, survey.questions where idsurvey = 1
```

it will only return 2 rows? (based on sample data in the workbench screenshot)

Any comments and suggestions on my diagram would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read about join. Your query returns a crossprooduct

Comment: thank you! @Jens I've totally forgotten about those clauses. My last db lessons were 5 years ago and now totally clueless on what to learn next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have two tables in the `from` clause, every row from the first table is matched with every table from the second table. This is known as a Cartesian Product. Usually, this isn't the behavior you'd want (like it isn't in this case), and you'd use a condition to tell the database how to match these two tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM   survey.survey s, survey.questions q
WHERE  s.idsurvey = q.survey_id AND idsurvey = 1
```

While this should work, it's quite outdated to use multiple tables in the same `from` clause. You should probably use an explicit `join` clause instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM   survey.survey s
JOIN   survey.questions q ON s.idsurvey = q.survey_id
WHERE  idsurvey = 1
```

Comment: YOU'RE AMAZING! it totally worked. thank you. i will read more about those what you have mentioned. it will give me a huge head start.